# How to show that the following is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Is $\dfrac{(p-1)!}{r!(p-r)!}$ always an integer for $p$ prime and $ 0<r<p$? where $r,p\in \Bbb Z$

Now $\dfrac{(p-1)!}{r!(p-r)!}=\dfrac{(p-1)(p-2)....(p-r+1)(p-r)!}{(p-r)!r!}=\dfrac{(p-1)(p-2)....(p-r+1)}{r!}$

$r!=r(r-1)(r-2)....3.2.1$

Now since $p$ is prime and hence odd so $p-1$ is even and hence the factor $2$ in $r!$ will cancel out $p-1$.

My specific question is how **To cancel the other factors in the denominator with the numerator**.

Please provide some hints on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Prove that $\dbinom{p}r$ is an integer. [See here for a proof.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3ev3vs34stx5a8/Product_of_consecutive_integers.pdf?dl=0)
2. Since $p$ is a prime, with $r<p$, we have $\gcd(p,r!) = 1$, $\gcd(p,(p-r)!) = 1$ and hence $\gcd(p,r!(p-r)!) = 1$.
3. From the above two, we have that $r!(p-r)!$ divides $p \cdot (p-1)!$ and that $\gcd(p,r!(p-r)!) = 1$, hence $r!(p-r)!$ divides $(p-1)!$. (Recall that if $a$ divides $bc$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $a$ divides $c$)

Comment: If a set $S$ has $n$ members,and $0\leq m\leq n,$ then the number of subsets of  $S$ that have exactly $m$ members each is $\binom {n}{m}=n!/m!(n-m)!$ which of course is an integer.

Comment: @user254665 Yes, that is a combinatorial proof of the first statement. There is also a purely number theoretic proof (Look at the third proof in the document linked) and another one purely on double induction (second proof).

Comment: Leg, you don't need a proof for the first statement. If you don't see that I'll ask you to prove why 1+1=2.

Comment: @aboat I disagree. It depends on where one wants to draw the line but the statement viewed purely as the product of $r$ number is divisible by $r!$ is non-trivial and deserves a proof. Of course, interpreting it combinatorially gives a immediate proof (but some are not satisfied with combinatorial proofs).

Answer (score 0):

Hint multiply and divide by $(p-r-1)!$ thus our term becomes $${p-1\choose r}.(p-r-1)!$$ which is total number of ways of selecting suppose $p-1$ people for r places and the number $p-r-1$ is an integer as $p,r\in Z$ thus the given number is an integer.